# How to get async data which is stored in the service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-httpclient

I'm fetching data from http, store it inside the same service in an array.

```
export class UserService {
    myusers: User[];
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    getUsers () {
     return this.http.get<User[]>('https://randomuser.me/api/results=5')
    .subscribe( data => { this.myusers = data['results']}); }
}
```

When I console myusers in component.ts it prints 'Undefined'.

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: UserService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUsers();
    console.log(this.service.myusers); //undefined
  }
}
```

So how can I access the `this.service.myusers`? Dont suggest the solution which stores the data in component's array not in service myusers array.

Comment: Please look into the docs of rxjs. read about observables and promise. your data is async. . You can't expect the service to return the value when you call it, so you should return the Observable in your service and subscribe to it in your component.

Comment: So there is no way to store data(array) in service? But I think this is a good approach as i can use this array in other components also without calling http.get() again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As returning data from API takes a bit time, so you need a callback from your service regarding completion of the job.

```
export class UserService {
    myusers: User[];
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    getUsers () {
        return this.http.get<User[]>('https://randomuser.me/api/results=5');
    }
    setUsers (users: User[]) {
        this.myusers = users;
    }
}
```

Call the function like below :

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: UserService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUsers()
    .subscribe( data => { this.service.setUsers(data); console.log(data); });
  }
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't serve your purpose

Comment: This fullfills my condition. for creating a list *ngFor = "let user of service.myusers". Is this a good approach?

Comment: As I can understand from your comment above, you may approach a caching approach for avoiding multiple calls for same request. A good approach is to always ask the service to get the details and service decides if it has to return a cached response or a fresh response by making a API call

Answer (score 2):

you always can return an Observable from a array using Observable.of

```
valores=[{id:1,nombre:"uno"},{id:2,nombre:"dos"},{id:3,nombre:"tres"}];

getUsers()
{ 
    if (this.valores)
       return Observable.of(this.valores);
    else 
        return this.http.get(url).map((response)=>
        this.valores=...
        ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service should be like.

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @Injectable()

    export class UserService {
        constructor(private http: Http) {}

        getUsers (): Observable<void> {
            const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/results=5';
            return this.http.get(url).map(
                (res: Response) => {
                  return res.json() as = User[];
                }).catch(
                (error: Response) => {
                    return Observable.throw(error.json());
                });
        }
    }
```

Component should be like

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[] = [];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  private getUsers(): void {
       this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
         (response: User[]) => {
           this.users = response;
           console.log(response); 
        );
    }       
}
```

Note: angular4 based on type script. so as per best practice you need to assign a type into method and variables.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it doesn't save the data in service myusers array.

Comment: Check my answer. if you want, feel free to post your completed solution